# tomcat stop processing after approx 4 minutes

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

We have one tomcat whenever we restart tomcat , then tomcat accept request for 4 min approx after 4 min it stop processing request we have increased thread count, checked catalina logs but didnt found anything

restart tomcat
checked logs
checked tomcat permission
increased thread count

Comment: Start the tomcat ans wait for 5 minutes before making request. Does the request get processes? What is error you are getting when the request is not being processed? Is the web application a simple HTML based application or dies it use server side components like servlets, web-services, JSP etc. Please provide detailed information to understand the problem better